# ASCIIMath support, to help people with units

Tags: discussion, feature-request, latex, mathjax

MathJax just added ASCIIMath support, and I think it'd be great to support it as an option, alongside regular \$\LaTeX\$-based MathJax.

In many posts (such as [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/how-do-i-deal-with-square-cubic-etc-zeros-and-poles-when-manually-drawing-a-b)) people forget to or are too lazy to properly format units:

> What we see: `\$5 kg\$` (\$5 kg\$)
>
> What we should see (pretty!): `\$5~\mathrm{kg}\$` (\$5~\mathrm{kg}\$).

In ASCIIMath, you can use quotation marks ("") to delimit roman text, so the properly formatted variant becomes `` \`5\ "kg"` ``.

Comment: Is it also lighter? anyway in my defense, I didn't know how to format units :)

Comment: :) I wasn't bashing you, I just couldn't find another example quickly enough.

Comment: But i'm not the poster, just one of those who make the mistake :)

Comment: That's what I get for doing two things at the same time.